# Class method doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement a class, name Coord, and it receives a name as a param, but when I create an instance of it, and try to call It's method, It doesn't work

```js
class Coordenador {
  constructor(nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.demanda = 0;
    this.custoUnitario = 0;
    this.capitalInicialEmpresas = 0;
    this.numeroRodadas = 0;
    this.isDefined = false;
    this.type = "COORDENADOR";
  }

  definirDados(demanda, custo, capital, rodadas) {
    this.demanda = demanda;
    this.custoUnitario = custo;
    this.capitalInicialEmpresas = capital;
    this.numeroRodadas = rodadas;
    this.isDefined = true;
  }
}
const c = new Coordenador("test");
c.definirDadosDaRodada(1200, 1000, 1000, 5);
```

I really can't understand why I'm getting this error

```js
setDadosJogo.js:111 Uncaught TypeError: c.definirDados is not a function
```

Comment: definirDadosDaRodada is your function. You're calling definirDados

Comment: You could add function to before definitDados

Comment: I was sending the whole instance to my server using socket.io, and then sending it back to the client, so my method was being lost. Already fixed it, thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 1):

Check what method you're calling. It's not the one you defined.